# JQUERY tools: is it possible to expose two elements?

Tags: jquery, jquery-tools

I need to [expose](http://flowplayer.org/tools/toolbox/expose.html)() 2 tr elements at the same time. Is it possible somehow?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As with any other jQuery function. Just use jQuery selectors:

```
$('#tr1, #tr2').expose();
```

Comment: Geez ( It failed in ie7. Any ideas?

Comment: @pukipuki, looks like a bug of expose

Answer (score 1):

If you mean make visible, then sure.

**CSS**:

```
tr { display: none; }
```

**HTML**:

```
<span class="exposeNow">EXPOSE</span>

<table>
    <tr class="exposeMe">
        <td>Some stuff</td>
        <td>in here too</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="exposeMe">
        <td>Some stuff</td>
        <td>in here too</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>This one won't</td>
        <td>get shown on click</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>This one won't</td>
        <td>get shown on click</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**jQuery**:

```
$("span.exposeNow").click(function(){
    $("tr.exposeMe").show();
});
```

Comment: Still relevant, simply replace .show() with .expose() - thanks! :-)

Comment: Mitch ) Do you have any solution without usage of a class attribute and still compartible with ie?

Answer (score 0):

If this is about http://flowplayer.org/tools/demos/toolbox/expose/index.html

I'm afraid you might not be able to do it with 2 tr's at the same time.

Comment: ... and unfortunately - does not in IE (((

Comment: Have you tried changing your table-layout mode to get it to work?
try table-layout:fixed

Comment: fixed layout did not helped (